# Classification of all functions satisfying $f$ such that $f(x)=f(x^2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functional-equations

I know that of functional identity $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$, $y=kx$ is definitely a solution. Other solutions may be constructed by treating the real numbers as a vector field over the rational numbers, which are pathological.

**How to construct all pathological functions satisfying the identity $f(x)=f(x^2)$?** I know that f must be constant if it's continuous, but what are the other cases?

Comment: $f(0)$ can be any value you want. Then partition $\mathbb{R}$ according to the relation $x\sim y$ if there are $m,n$ such that $x^{2^m}=y^{2^n}$. Give $f$ any value you want on each orbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited 4 Jan to incorporate details I skipped pointed out by user517969.

Let $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ be periodic with period $\log 2$, let $a,b\in\mathbb R$.  Then $$f(x)=\begin{cases}a & \text{if }x=0\\\phi(\log(-\log|x|))&0<|x|<1\\b&|x|=1\\\psi(\log(\log(|x|))&|x|>1\end{cases}$$
satisfies your functional equation , and can be as pathological (or as smooth) as $\phi$ and $\psi$ are.  Because $f(-x)=f(x)$ there is no loss of generality in using the absolute value signs in the innermost logarithm.  I *think* this is the most general form of solution.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems very general and many functions can be applied to as a reply. For instance one tricky function inspired by Dirichlet function is: $f(x)=0$ for transcendental numbers and 1 elsewhere.

Comment: What I want is to classify such functions **completely**, not just a special case.

Comment: Put $g(x)=f(e^{x})$. The equation becomes $g(2x)=g(x)$ which  is simpler. Any solution g to the last equation gives a solution to the original equation because f is necessarily an even function  so $f(x)=g(ln|x|)$ for $x \neq 0$. f(0) is arbitrary.